# Timeout for authentication_token only, not for database authenticable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In `config/initializers/devise.rb` file,

```
config.timeout_in = 30.minutes
```

But this affects both users logging from browser and also, resets auth_token I think. But, I need to reset auth_token only after a small amount of time. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can control the behavior of the token timeout through creating a class method called `expire_auth_token_on_timeout` in your User model. If this method is set devise will reset the token upon timeout (alongside the user session). (This is defined in [timeoutable.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb#L22))

Now if you want to expire the auth token sooner than that you can just hook into the same warden hook and check this yourself and call `record.reset_authentication_token!` yourself.

The callback in question is `after_set_user` as described in [the warden wiki](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Callbacks)

But you have to think about how you go about this and maybe create a seperate timestamp in your model that logs the last auth-token access to make sure you expire it after a certain amount of time. (You should also be able to determine if the request is a token request through the request object - keep in mind you are at the rack level, thus you can access the request through the env object).

I am sorry I can't provide any sample code for this, but you'll have to play around with the implementation and I don't have a test-case handy.